# Replace Arraylist with everything except for numbers in Java

Tags: java, string, arraylist, replaceall

I have a Arraylist, like this:

```
ArrayList<String> moisturizersPrices = [Price: Rs. 365, Price: Rs. 299, Price: Rs. 12, Price: 220, Price: 95, Price: 216]
```

for that I am using following logic:

```
moisturizersPrices.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "")
```

and it is returning me something like this:

```
[.365, .299, .12, 220, 95, 216]
```

Now I want to remove all characters from there, except for numeric, such as it should be giving me results like this:

```
[365, 299, 12, 220, 95, 216]
```

I need to know, where I am making mistake.

Comment: I don’t think your code is complete and correct. A [mre], please?

Comment: There is a period (dot, `.`) after each occurrence of `Rs`. Since you ask for everything ecept digits 0 thourgh 9 *and periods* to be placed with empty strings, periods remain.

Comment: You never said you wanted to convert them to Integers.  Please amend your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a `Pattern` match like

```java
List<String> moisturizersPrices = List.of(
    "Price: Rs. 365",
    "Price: Rs. 299", 
    "Price: Rs. 12", 
    "Price: 220", 
    "Price: 95", 
    "Price: 216"
);
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+$");
List<Integer> numbers = moisturizersPrices.stream()
    .map(p::matcher)
    .filter(Matcher::find)
    .map(m -> Integer.parseInt(m.group()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

```
[365, 299, 12, 220, 95, 216]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it very simply like this. Just replace every non-Digit `(\\D)` with an empty string.

```
 List<String> moisturizers = new ArrayList<>(
         List.of("Price: Rs. 365", "Price: Rs. 299", "Price: Rs. 12",
                 "Price: 220", "Price: 95", "Price: 216"));

 moisturizers.replaceAll(str->str.replaceAll("\\D",""));
 System.out.println(moisturizers);
```

prints

```
[365, 299, 12, 220, 95, 216]
```

If you want to convert them to a `List<Integer>`, do it like this.

```
List<Integer> results = moisturizers.stream()
        .map(str -> Integer.parseInt(str.replaceAll("\\D", "")))
        .toList();
System.out.println(results);
```

prints the same as above

If you have other digits elsewhere, then use the following regex. It will replace *all* characters up to the digits at the end of the string with those captured in the parentheses.  The `$1` is a back reference to those digits.

```
str.replaceAll(".*?(\\d+)$", "$1")
```